# Get icons' lnk filenames on Windows 11 desktop

Tags: python, windows, icons, desktop

I would like to rearrange the icons on my Windows 11 desktop, grouping them based on the lnk filenames. I could change their positions based on the icons' indexes but how can I know which lnk files belong to the icons? For example I have "Adobe Acrobat.lnk" on my Desktop as 2nd icon:

```
import commctrl
import win32gui

search_criteria = (
        (0, "Progman", None),
        (0, "SHELLDLL_DefView", None),
        (0, "SysListView32", None),
    )

whnd = 0
for criteria in search_criteria:
    whnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(whnd, *criteria)
    if whnd == 0:
        print(f'Could not find child matching criteria: {criteria}')
        stop()

index = 2       # !!! I would like to know which lnk file belongs to this index to position it !!!

# Then I could move it to its proper position
x, y = 500, 300
lparam = (x << 16) | y
win32gui.SendMessage(whnd, commctrl.LVM_SETITEMPOSITION, index, lparam)
```